# How to count Observable on incomplete sequence in Rx.js

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, reactive-programming, rxjs

I have an obeservable sequence, where each time a call realease event occurs I map that event to an http request that returns some call logs that I then filter and need to get a count form. The problem is that even though the mapped obserbable that returns the json from the http request and the sequence has completed the orginal fromEvent Observable has not terminated so count will not emit anything. I need a count of the filtered amount each time the http request comes back not sure how to do this.

```
var seq = Rx.Observable
        .fromEvent(call realease event)
        .flatMap(agentObj => 
          Rx.Observable.fromPromise(callLogHelper.getUserCallLogs(agentObj.agentId))
        )
        .flatMap(logs => Rx.Observable.fromArray(logs))
        .filter(log => log.callTime >= 210)
        .count();
```

I tried a few methods that very helpful people offered including user3743222 , which i am very thankful for. These included scan, sample, expand and using the idx argument in map and filter. The main issue i keep getting is that these methods return a continuous running total and because the http request can have duplicate data from the last time it was called the running count needs to be reset each time the http request is returned.

I ended up just mapping the filtered values from the request in the flatMap as simple array operations and then just returning the length. I feel like this is a hacky solution tho

```
var seq = Rx.Observable
        .fromEvent(call realease event)
        .flatMap(agentObj => 
             Rx.Observable.fromPromise(callLogHelper.getUserCallLogs(agentObj.agentId))
        )
        .flatMap((logs) => {
             var filteredLogs = logs.filter(log => log.callTime >= 210);
             return  Rx.Observable.of(filteredLogs.length);
         })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the solution you came up with it would seem simpler to just do:

```
var seq = Rx.Observable
        .fromEvent(call realease event)
        .flatMap(
          agentObj => callLogHelper.getUserCallLogs(agentObj.agentId),
          (ao, logs) => logs.filter(log => log.callTime >= 210).length
        );
```

Comment: That is much more elegant, Thank You

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use the [`scan`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/scan.html) operator. In practice, it would be something like :

```
var seq = Rx.Observable
        .fromEvent(call realease event)
        .flatMap(flatMap(agentObj => 
          Rx.Observable.fromPromise(callLogHelper.getUserCallLogs(agentObj.agentId))
        ))
        .flatMap(logs => Rx.Observable.fromArray(logs))
        .filter(log => log.callTime >= 210)
        .scan (function (count, _){return ++count},0);
```

Comment: Tried that but the http response can emit the same results more than once so scan continually adds counts that may be duplicates

Comment: Please update your question accordingly. If you forget anything else, please also add it to the question. Generally speaking, review http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It is always annoying to spend time answering questions which are ill-defined or incomplete. I'll give you the corresponding answer once that is done.

Comment: I apologize its not that I forgot, its the question evolved since i first posted and I tried other techniques offered to me from github and slack, but I do apologize for the incovenience

Comment: There is the `distinct` operator that could be of use to you. `distinctUntilChanged` is interesting too but probably not what you are looking for. As a matter of fact `distinct` ensures that no two same items will pass through. That also means that it keeps a buffer of the items who already went through and that buffer is not unbounded so if you have a volubile source, you might want to go for an ad-hoc solution

Comment: I thought of that but I am worried about memory usage. Have not looked at distinctUntillChanged however

Comment: If you think about it, if you don't keep a memory of the past responses, you cannot detect duplicates. So in your proposed answer, that memory is a log. With `distinct` it is an array. But that ever-growing structure is unavoidable. Now I would agree that if you already have that information stored somewhere in a log, and performance of access of that log is ok, you can avoid duplicating it with a second buffer.

Comment: Ya its stored on  a separate server,  and accessible.

Comment: Thanks for all you input